# How to optimize a generalized trace problem in dimensionality reduction

Tags: optimization, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

I know how to solve this problem in dimensionality reduction.

$argmax_{X}$ $Trace[XLX^T]$ with $XX^T=I$ ,where $L$ is symmetric, $X$ is unitary, and $I$ is identity matrix.

But I'd like to know how to solve more generalized problem like

$argmax_{X,Y}$ $Trace[XL_1X^T+YL_2Y^T+(X+Y)L_3(X+Y)^T]$ with some contraint.

Could you let me know any tips or good references for this problem please?

Comment: Any context for the problem?